# cannot figure out how to solve the hangman display in python

Tags: python

I am having trouble figuring out how to do the hangman display in my python hangman game. How my current code is working under my display_word function is that it will show a '-' for any word that is my hangman word. When I guess a letter correct it will shorten the '-' display by the number of letter are in the string. I would like instead for this display to add that letter to the display and still hold the '-''s for the letters I haven't guessed. Can anyone solve this?

```
from random import choice
    
    print('Welcome to Hangman!!!, Guess the secret word ')
    
    org_word = choice(['wallee'])
    word = set(org_word)
    already_guessed = ''
    correct_letters = ''
    chances = 2
    
    def hang_man():
        while not check_win():
            guess()
    
    
    def guess():
        global chances
        global correct_letters
        global already_guessed
    
        if chances > 0:
            display_word()
            user_guess = input('\nWhat is your guess at the secret word?  ')
                #check for valid input
            if len(user_guess) > 1 or not user_guess.isalpha():
                print('you entered an invalid input and you lost a guess')
                chances -= 1
                check_loss()
                #check if letter was already guessed
            elif user_guess in already_guessed:
                print('you already entered that letter and you lost a guess')
                chances -=1
                check_loss()
                #incorrect guess
            elif user_guess not in word:
                print('\nThat guess was not in the word and you lost a guess')
                chances -= 1
                already_guessed += user_guess
                check_loss()
                #correct guess
            elif len(user_guess) == 1 and user_guess in word:
                print(f'\nGreat, your guess of {user_guess} was in the word')
                correct_letters += user_guess
                word.remove(user_guess)
    #need help here
    def display_word():
        global correct_letters
        stringed_word = (str(org_word)[:])
        for char in stringed_word:
            if char not in correct_letters:
                print(char.replace(char, '-'), end='')
    #need help here 
    
    def check_win():
        if len(word) == 0:
            print(f'Congrats, you guessed the correct word {org_word}')
            return True
    
    def check_loss():
        if chances == 0:
            print('Sorry you are out of guesses, You Lost :(')
        else:
            print(f'you now have {chances} guesses left')
    
    
    hang_man()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making this much harder than it needs to be.  For each letter, if it was guessed, print the letter, otherwise print a dash. No replacing required.

```
    def display_word():
        for char in org_word:
            if char in correct_letters:
                print(char, end=' ')
            else:
                print('-', end=' ')
```

Comment: great solution tim!!